# Are $g(x) = 2 \cdot \log(x)$ and $ f(x) = \log(x^2)$ the same function?

Tags: functions, logarithms

$$g(x) = 2 \cdot \log(x)$$ $$ f(x) = \log(x^2)$$

The domain of the two functions are different. The domain of $g(x) \text{ is } (0, \infty)$ while the domain of $f(x) \text{ is } \mathbb{R} - \{0\} $.

We can show that both the functions are equivalent by applying the power rule. But are two functions the same, as their domain is different?

Comment: If you define $g:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ and $f:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ then they are the same function. Allowing $f$ to take negative values makes $f(x)\neq g(x)$ for $x<0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No by definition. Two functions are called equal iff they share the same domain and have the same functional value everywhere on the domain. Since $f$ and $g$ thus defined have different domains, they are not the same function. But you may say that $g$ restricted on $]0, +\infty[$ is $f$, for then they have the same domain and the same functional values.

Comment: This is not quite true. To be equal, the functions must also have the same range. This is not necessarily the image set, but the set into which each maps the domain. Explicitly: two functions $f:X\to Y$ and $g:A\to B$ are equal if (1) $X=A$; (2) $Y=B$; and (3) $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: @MPW, Hello, you are confused with the concept. Note that two functions having the same domain and the same values everywhere implies they have the same range. Best guess is that you confuse codomain with that of range. You can use this opportunity to refresh them! Cheer up.

Comment: No, I am not confused. I meant precisely what I said. The terminology differs, to be sure, so let me clarify: for a function $f:X\to Y$, the domain of $f$ is $X$, the range of $f$ is $Y$, and the image of $f$ is $f(X)$. These are the definitions behind my statement. Feel free to make the corresponding statement in the language of your own definitions, but there's no getting around the fact that you have ignored that $f(X)$ and $Y$ are definitely *not* necessarily the same, nor need they be. Equality of these functions requires precisely what I said in (1), (2), and (3). Period.

Comment: (continued) And your answer absolutely ignores the point (2). It is definitely NOT ENOUGH that only (1) and (3) are satisfied.

Comment: @MPW, I did not feel something is not right before seeing "getting around". I will overlook it, never mind. Using your notation, by codomain I mean $Y$ and by range I mean $f(X)$. And $f(X) := \{ f(x) \mid x \in X \}$. I don't see what is wrong from your perspective. If you are uncomfortable with verbal description, try to get used to it and eventually it will benefit your learning :). This is just for your good: "having the same value everywhere on the domain" means "$f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x \in X$", meaning $f(X) = g(X)$, meaning the range of $f$ is the range of $g$. Please feel free to ask.

Comment: You understand that the map produced by restricting or extending the domain is a different map, right? And likewise, the map produced by restricting or extending the codomain is a different map. Example: the functions $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb C$, $h:[0,1] \to[0,1]$, $k:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ all with the rule $x\mapsto x$ are all different functions. They are all "like" the identity function, but different in a subtle way.

Comment: @MPW,  I don't know what you are talking about now. Elaborating more would help the situation. What I can tell you is if $A \subset X$ then $f|_{A}(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in A$. So the range of $f|_{A}$ agrees with the image of $A$ under $f$.

Comment: It is simply incorrect to say that a function is determined by its domain and its rule of assignment. In saying this, you are completely omitting the target space into which the function maps the domain. I can't say it more clearly. I offered specific examples. In each of these examples, the functions are different, even though the rule of assignment is ostensibly the same for each of them. $0$ regarded as an element of $\mathbb R$ is a different point than $0$ regarded as an element of $[0,1]$, and is a different point than $0$ regarded as an element of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @MPW, I am not sure why you bring that in. More than one time you kept claiming that I am wrong. From my perspective, you are more like someone who wishes that I am wrong by finding fault with what I say. If you are a news reporter, great; but please try reporter.S.E. something. Recall that people here are supposed to solve OP's question. And now I  do not know what your intention is. Please try to find more constructive activities to partake. This would be the last time I reply to a harassment down here.

Comment: @MPW You are just wrong. By the definition of a function, a function is uniquely determined by its domain, and its rule of assignment. The codomain of a function is not unique, because it can be any superset of the range, which by definition, is the image of the domain under the function. A function is merely a set of Kuratowski pairs: a subset of a Cartesian product, to be precise. Two distinct Cartesian products can share elements, and thus share non-trivial subsets. So, you are completely wrong. Of the requirements you listed, only (1) and (3) need be satisfied for functional equality.

Comment: @MPW Your non-standard of usage of language, under the pretense of it being standard, is disingenuous and frivolous. Also, you are wrong about something else. You claim that $0\in\mathbb{R}$, $0\in[0,1]$, and $0\in\mathbb{C}$ are all distinct mathematical objects. This is only partially accurate: while $0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $0\in\mathbb{C}$ are genuinely distinct, $0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $0\in[0,1]$ are genuinely the same object, since by definition, $[0,1]:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:0\leq{x}\leq1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is because the rules of exponents don't always work for negative bases, and unfortunately, the property
$$2\ln x=\ln x^2$$
Only holds for positive $x$, for the same reason
$$a^2=b^2\implies a=b$$
only for positive $a,b$.

For example, suppose we have $\ln(1)=0$. Then, using this rule,
$$\ln(1)=0$$
$$\ln((-1)^2)=0$$
$$2\ln(-1)=0$$
$$\ln(-1)=0$$
But this simply isn't true. It's the same as the classic fallacy
$$-1=(-1)^{2/2}=\sqrt{(-1)^2}=1$$
And so it just doesn't make sense to apply the power rule when you are taking the logarithm of a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

$$\log{x^2}=2\log|x|,$$
which says $f\neq g$.

Answer (score 0):

Note:
$$\ln{x^2}=2\ln{|x|}\ne 2\ln{x}.$$